# No .lib and .dll found, but .h is there

Tags: c++, dll, lib, rtaudio

So I'm trying to use RtAudio to read microphone input in real time, but the problem is that when I download the .zip file, I found the header files but there is no .lib files or dll, and I need them Link with my project, where are they?

I'm a beginner in cpp:)

This is the RtAudio
https://github.com/thestk/rtaudio

Comment: Use CMake to produce a project file for your compiler or IDE. Build that project file.

Comment: @drescherjm how can I do that? sorry, I'm very new to this

Comment: That depends on your IDE. Visual Studio Community and several other IDEs can use a CMakeLists.txt directly so they do the work for you if you want them.

Comment: @drescherjm my IDE is Visual, but Cmake will give me only the lib files and dll?

Comment: Just open the `CMakeLists.txt` in Visual Studio Community and build all configurations in both Debug mode and Release. That should produce the libraries, dlls, tests and other applications related to the project.

Comment: @drescherjm in the CMakeLists.txt there is a lor of configurations that I don't get

Comment: @drescherjm Im very confuse

Comment: If you are confused by using CMake directly in Visual Studio Community you can use it directly using this tutorial: [https://cmake.org/runningcmake/](https://cmake.org/runningcmake/) you can download CMake here: [https://cmake.org/install/](https://cmake.org/install/)

Comment: @drescherjm alr, I'm going to check that:)

Comment: @drescherjm I'm done, It create a build folder with a bunch of files that are not .lib and .dll

Comment: I think someone familiar with this particular library has to explain exactly what to expect and how to use the source code.

Comment: how?, I used the CMake Gui

Comment: Normally in CMake after you configure and Generate you open up the project in Visual Studio and can build all in Debug and Release to get everything that is included in the default settings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241792/discussion-between-bernardo-olisan-and-drescherjm).

Comment: @drescherjm I put some messages in the chat

Comment: @drescherjm so what I did wrong?

Comment: I know CMake and have used it thousands of times since I started using it at work in 2008. However I don't use this library. Most CMake based software operates the same way that is why I attempted to give you advice based on what I would expect for a library. I don't think I can help further without downloading and trying myself however I don't have the time at the moment.

Comment: @drescherjm the is also a makefile, is that different?

Comment: A makefile could be used by NMake or mingw-make + mingw depending on what type of makefile was generated. You said you were using Visual Studio. Are you using VSCode that is a totally different IDE with a similar name.

Comment: @drescherjm I have both VSCode and Visual

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have downloaded a copy of source code repository. Compiled binaries such libraries are not stored in such repositories. That's why you won't find them there.

In order to get the compiled libraries from the source code, you must compile i.e. build the source code. Each project has their own way of building from source, although there  are common patterns. The frontpage that you link to contains instructions on how to build that project. The instructions to build it are under the heading "Building".